# Drupal Omega Theme

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to understand Omega theme in Drupal.

I cannot understand the js class that is referred in the  tag in html5 starterkit. I figured that I had to tweak style settings there in order to adjust the height of sections/ zones or regions in terms of percentage.

What is that js class in the html tag?

Comment: What js-class do you mean? Are you using omega3 or omega4?

Comment: And what js-class or which tag do you mean?